# WebSocket on React Native Android gives "undefined is not a function"

Tags: android, websocket, react-native

I am trying to create a WebSocket connection in a React Native Android app, using the [Network polyfill](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html):

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var wstest = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    ws.on('connect', function() {
      console.log('connected');
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      // ... left out for brevity
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // ... left out for brevity
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('wstest', () => wstest);
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating 'ws.on('connect',function() { ...
```

[Reload JS error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUW5M.png)

Is there something in the build environment that I need to set up or configure for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same problem. It seems Facebook's React Native docs on WS is incorrect. The correct way to listen for messages on WS is by the following:

```
    var ws = new WebSocket(url);

    ws.onopen = (() => {
        console.log("connection opened.");
    });

    ws.onmessage = ((message) => {
        console.log(message.data);
    });

    ws.onerror = ((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
    });

    ws.onclose = ((event) => {
        console.log(event.code, event.reason);
    });
```

Comment: It looks like this part of the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#websocket) has been updated now.